# ListView's checkedItemCount() greater than ListAdapter's getCount()

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I was looking through the android source code and I came across this 
[line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/ed71af9/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/MiscFilesHandler.java#101) where a check is made to ensure the number of items checked (got from the ListView object) doesn't exceed the number of items in the ListAdapter. I've added the same piece of code below. `mDataCount` is the number of items in the list adapter.

```
int checkedCount = getListView().getCheckedItemCount();
if (checkedCount > mDataCount) {
   throw new IllegalStateException("checked item counts do not match. " +
                            "checkedCount: " + checkedCount + ", dataSize: " + mDataCount);
}
```

I was wondering why this was necessary because the list view always takes data from the adapter and in no case can the number of items in a list view be greater than the number of items in an adapter.

Thanks